# software recomendations

Tags: web-apps, python, software-development, dashboard

I have been working on a project related to data and web application in Python and machine learning. I have been using [Spyder from Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/spyder) for coding purpose.

I have installed some libraries regarding Dashboard, Googlesheets, API etc. Now when I run the Spyder App, it doesn't run.

So anyone can give me any idea to switch over another software where I can run code regarding web app and dashboard.

Comment: On a site called "software recommendations", the title "software recommendations" seems redundant to me. Please let your title describe what you're looking for.

Comment: We don't help fixing broken software here. Maybe (!) such things can be asked on superuser.com

Comment: Welcome. If you think of title which actually says what you are looking for, more people will read it. With this title, not many ill bother. If you can't give it any effort, why should they?

Comment: Rewrite title to be specific.

Answer (score 0):

Django on python is your best bet for this, seeing as you may already be accustomed to pythons methods, install it through pip, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ is the Django docs.